# How to check local storage size in safari browser

Tags: safari, local-storage

i am doing HTML5 mobile application in sencha touch2. i have used local storage, i know how to delete cache and reset safari etc. i want to know how to see the local storage size in safari browser.

Comment: thank you for your reply...it is giving how many number of storage using..i need size of total local storage.

Comment: JSON.stringify(localStorage).length

Comment: Thank you. i got answer.helpful..it is returning 29990 how to convert this one in KB.

Comment: To get KB you just divide the number with 1024. Also I think that the data is stored as UTF16 so to get the data in KB you would multiply it first by 2

JSON.stringify(localStorage).length * 2 / 1024